# how to replay messages in kafka topic based on timestamp?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to replay Kafka topic data based on timestamp. I was able to seek the data from starting position but then I need to check the endtimestamp for the records in each partition. When i try to compare record's timestamp with endtimestamp, the loop breaks right at the first partition.

```java
for(TopicPartition partition : records.partitions() ) {
  for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record : records) {
    if (record.timestamp() >= endtimeStamp) {
      consumer.seektoend(partition);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code only breaks from the inner loop. It should still be processing all other partitions. It would only break the outer loop if you only have one partition anyway

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah but  it was not returning all data, I have a 20 partitions after some times it was looping inside the partitions but i breaked the loop whenever record timestamp matched with end timestamp ...!! But still it was looping ???

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will always break during first partition (if there is at least one record with timestamp() >= endtimeStamp though) because for each partition, you're iterating over all your records.

```
for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record : records) {
    if (record.timestamp() >= endtimeStamp) {
      consumer.seektoend(partition);
      break;
    }
  }
```

==> Here you're doing all records whatever the partition is. You will call seekToEnd() for the same partition again and again

Yannick